# NSIS - Custom page, custom size, custom OK and Cancel button, with custom fields

Tags: window, nsis

I'm relatively new to NSIS. I want to create an extra page before MUI_PAGE_WELCOME.
I've tried [NSIS Dialog Designer](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/NSIS_Dialog_Designer), but it uses the Modern UI for its template.
I'd like to achieve a completely custom window, with different size, with radio buttons, text fields, and OK- instead of Next button on the bottom, without the MUI overlay.

Are there programs to design pages like this? Maybe I have to use Qt Creator, Visual Studio, or [EclipseNSIS](http://eclipsensis.sourceforge.net/index.shtml) for this? Creating Plugins, inserting them somehow to my NSIS document ..

Any simple solutions?

[image: Custom Page without Modern UI]

Comment: Having windows that change in size are a real pain to deal with. Why can't you just create the window with a normal size?

Comment: This may be the solution: nsWindows plugin instead nsDialogs - http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=304431 - I'll have to check it out later.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for complete UI change, which is of course possible but it requires a lot of work, like this one: [image: Small window]

or

[image: Visual_UI]

There is not an exact step-by-step tutorial, you need to experiment (some NSIS knowledge is required).

Here is short list what to do:

Modify the UI file with **Resource Hacker** (http://angusj.com/resourcehacker/)

Then use **Graphical Installer** for background and buttons (http://graphical-installer.com/web/gallery.html#Technical)

And for creating the custom dialog use **Install Designer** (http://www.install-designer.com/)

But again there is no exact tutorial for your design, you need to use various tools and scripting to achieve the desired result.

P.S. I am developer of GI and ID tools above, feel free to contact me or ask any questions regarding them here on SO.

Comment: I know, i know of Ressource Hacker, that I can edit some of the NSIS pages, its sizes, etc. But every window have to be the same size as all other pages. As I test Install Designer, it behaves similarly to the free Dialog Designer - it still uses the MUI Modern template as the overlay. I'll have to deal with what is.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can do it in NSIS with [InstallOptions 2](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Docs/InstallOptions/Readme.html).

InstallOptions 2 offers mechanisms to create "Label", "Text", "Password", "Combobox", "DropList", "Listbox", "CheckBox", "RadioButton", "FileRequest", "DirRequest" "Icon", "Bitmap", "GroupBox", "HLine", "VLine", "Link" or "Button".

Here is a screenshot for the *Examples\InstallOptions\testnotify.nsi*.

[image: Examples\InstallOptions\testnotify.nsi]